# SBJSON parser wont update it's content

Tags: iphone, sbjson

I guess I'm not clear enough with the title, so here it goes:

I'm building an application that has a facebook login, but I use the SBJSON parser that the Facebook API has in it to parse other documents. Now the problem that I have is strange for me. The parser is not getting the updates that I make in the JSON that it reads.

I use this content:

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "catunique": "f874f7d2b48b099400e9f22ea512c234c4f89d81",
            "cattitle": "Nature",
            "catfold": "nature"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "catunique": "edfbb81a83e37b045bfddec1c4fbbbef52b408e7",
            "cattitle": "Bikes",
            "catfold": "bikes"
        }
    ],
    "images": [
        {
            "id": 31,
            "catunique": 5,
            "imgtag": "Pig",
            "imgname": "pig759.png",
            "imgbname": "pig759@2x.png"
        },
        {
            "id": 32,
            "catunique": 5,
            "imgtag": "Frog Shadow",
            "imgname": "frogshadow503.jpg",
            "imgbname": "frogshadow503@2x.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 33,
            "catunique": 3,
            "imgtag": "Cat",
            "imgname": "cat518.jpg",
            "imgbname": "cat518@2x.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is parsed OK but if I add another item in the "images" object I re-run the application and the response is not getting it.

in my App Delegate I have this code for using the parser

```
SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON alloc] init];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somedomain.com/images.json"]];
//[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
//[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyNever];

NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
//set data to string with encoding
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
imagesJsonData = [json objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
```

Can someone tell me if this is a server problem, Parser problem or my coding problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: you're using a *really ancient* version of SBJson. I recommend you use a more recent version. Second: are you sure your server is actually sending the new data file? Try looking at it in Safari / Firefox / Chrome. If the extra data is there, check if NSURLConnection is somehow caching your request. (Maybe append a random `?r=1234123` to the URI?)